# Making simulation deterministic (simulator based on qemu)

Tags: c++, simulator, qemu, deterministic

I am using Marss cycle-accurate simulator, which uses QEMU. It is a full system simulator and gives both user and kernel stats. 
However, even if I take only user-stats, the statistics vary a lot between different runs. I have asked this question on marss site, but could not get good answer.
I was wondering if it has something to do with qemu. Or any qemu option/variation, that can make simulation deterministic.
I tried using -icount auto and still some variation is there.
With simplescalar eio files, I have never observed any variation.
I would be grateful for some help.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used MARSS/QEMU, but I am familiar with the issue, with simulators in general, and with SimpleScalar.

It is very hard to make full system simulators in general deterministic. E.g. if your program prints the time of day, and the time of day changes, different code paths will be followed. More generally, if you are doing a full system simulation, and time ls, then the exact interleaving of OS and user code will differ based on the position of the disk head, how much data is in the disk cache, etc.  Let alone what other processes are running on the system.

SimpleScalar eio (and simulators in industry) provide determinism by recording a trace of external I/O events to apply to the simulation at exactly the same instruction count as in previous runs. Basically, you are only doing full system simulation when you record

You need to look for similar options for MARSS/QEMU.  Unfortunately, I have not found such.

Lacking these...

But I can hear you say "My program doesn't read the time of day. Shouldn't it run exactly the same way each time?"  Maybe so... but (1) many Linux libraruies do the moral equivalent of reading the time. And (2) there are other processes running user code.

So you need to control the run.  Don't boot your virtual machine (not a hardware virtual machine, i mean just the OS you are running on the simulator) all the way up.  Stop in singleuser. Edit /etc/rc to stop as many processes as possible running. Full system simulation is not unlike benchmarking on a real machine.  And on real machines, we may even reboot the machine afresh each time we run a benchmark. Disable (virtual) networking. Etc.

If you can, don't run on a real OS, but in a minimal monitor.

However, really best to find I/O trace replay facility.  Sometimes these hide under debugger options.

---

Here is a ref that talks, in 2008, about patches for I/O replay in qemu.

http://wiki.qemu.org/Features/FaultTolerance - does I/O replay for reliability / fault tolerance.

QEMU user space emulation may be more reproducible. I do not know if it works in conjunction with MARSS

---

By the way: the issue of reproducibility is not just relevant to simulators.  It is also relevant to reliability, and to debugging.

You may be able to find a generic Linux replay facility, that you can use to make your system on top of QEMU/MARSS more reproducible.

---

Inside MARSS, you may be able to use the ptlcall checkpoint facilities to take a checkpoint just after the point where your benchmark (assuming you are running SPEC or the like) has done a lot of initial I/O, and before the next I.O.  Many benchmarks do a lot of initial I/O, then run in user code for a while, and then do some final I/O.  By using these checkpoints, you may be able to avoid time varying system calls.

Similarly Simpoints, http://www.marss86.org/~marss86/index.php/Simpoints

---

By the way, I was just reminded of another way programs may be non-deterministic (apart from accidentally depending on time, or multiprocessor interactions): they may explicitly and intrinsically depend on time.

E.g. the langer98 version of the Livermore Loops benchmark times how long a loop took, and if insufficient time is spent, ups the loop count.  You can record the external interactions, such as time and system calls here, and the program may become reproducible - but you won't be measuring exactly what it will do on your newer, faster, computer.

The converse: imagine that you have a compiler optimization switch of the form "apply this really expensive optimization for no more than 2 hours, then stop..."

Answer (score 0):

**QEMU built-in deterministic record and replay**

QEMU 2.9.0 now kind of has deterministic record and replay by saving external inputs, but it is broken temporarily: [How to use QEMU's deterministic record and replay feature for a Linux kernel boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46970215/how-to-use-qemus-deterministic-record-and-replay-feature-for-a-linux-kernel-boo)

The main documentations are:

- https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/v2.9.0/docs/replay.txt
- https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/record-replay