# How to use QEMU's deterministic record and replay feature for a Linux kernel boot?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, qemu

QEMU supports deterministic record and replay as documented at: https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/v2.9.0/docs/replay.txt

However, I could not get replay working for a full Linux kernel boot: it always hangs at some point.

These are the commands I'm running:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cmd="\
time \
./buildroot/output.x86_64~/host/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 \
-M pc \
-append 'root=/dev/sda console=ttyS0 nokaslr printk.time=y - lkmc_eval=\"/rand_check.out;wget -S google.com;/poweroff.out;\"' \
-kernel './buildroot/output.x86_64~/images/bzImage' \
-nographic \
\
-drive file=./buildroot/output.x86_64~/images/rootfs.ext2,if=none,id=img-direct,format=raw \
-drive driver=blkreplay,if=none,image=img-direct,id=img-blkreplay \
-device ide-hd,drive=img-blkreplay \
\
-netdev user,id=net1 \
-device rtl8139,netdev=net1 \
-object filter-replay,id=replay,netdev=net1 \
"
echo "$cmd"
eval "$cmd -icount 'shift=7,rr=record,rrfile=replay.bin'"
# Different than previous.
eval "$cmd -icount 'shift=7,rr=record,rrfile=replay.bin'"
# Same as previous.
eval "$cmd -icount 'shift=7,rr=replay,rrfile=replay.bin'"
```

and my kernel and root filesystem were generated with this Buildroot setup: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/0a1a600d49d1292be82a47cfde6f0355996478f0 which uses QEMU v2.9.0.

`lkmc_eval` gets evaled by my `init` scripts. Here we print userspace stuff that is usually random to check that we are actually deterministic, and then power off the machine.

How I came up with those commands:

- start from the working command I used in my repo without record replay
- copy paste the hard disk and networking parts from the wiki: https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/record-replay

The in-tree docs say there is no networking support, but the wiki and git log says they were added as of v2.9.0, so I think the docs are just outdated compared to the wiki.

Using that setup, the boot replay progresses quite far, but hangs at the message:

```
[   31.692427] NET: Registered protocol family 17
```

In the initial record, the next message would have been:

```
[   31.777326] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
```

so I'm suspicious that it is a block device matter.

The timestamps are however identical, so I'm confident that the record and replay has worked so far.

If for the networking I use just:

```
-net none
```

then the record itself hangs at:

```
[   19.669685] ALSA device list:
[   19.670756]   No soundcards found.
```

If anyone wants to try a QEMU patch against it, just checkout to your patch inside `/qemu/` and run:

```
./build -t host-qemu-reconfigure
```

to rebuild.

Answer (score 2):

Your command line looks ok, but unfortunately record/replay is QEMU is broken in this release.
I hope that it will be fixed in the nearest weeks.

Comment: Thanks for the news Pavel. When it gets fixed, please update the answer and ping me on a comment. This feature is pretty cool! Cheers.

Comment: Any updates on this? Is there a version (maybe old) or maybe a fork where record/replay works?

Comment: There is a DMA issue for guest Windows in Qemu 4.2. But it should be ok for Linux guest record/replay.

You can start from here: https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/docs/replay.txt